# Size of the Library/Executable is high in LINUX

Tags: c++, c, linux

We have a 32bit Gui application created using C++. We ported the application from Solaris to Linux. Issue we are facing is

the size of the library and executable is very large in LINUX compared to Solaris.

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.4 is the Linux version we using.

Please find a sample dynamic library created. We would like to know the following behavior of LINUX is normal or not.

Consider we created two files test1.cc and test2.cc. Both having a single line of code.

```
a-2720@N530 /data1/users/a-2720/samp :ls  -lrt test1.cc test2.cc

-rw-rw-r--   1 a-2720   mcs           21 May 18 06:16 test1.cc

-rw-rw-r--   1 a-2720   mcs           21 May 18 06:16 test2.cc


a-2720@N530 /data1/users/a-2720/samp :cat test1.cc

    #include<iostream.h>


a-2720@N530 /data1/users/a-2720/samp :cat test2.cc

    #include<iostream.h>
```

Thus the files have only only one line inside them

I created a Shared library using these files.

### SOLARIS

```
CC -c  -library=iostream  -g -mt test1.cc

CC -c  -library=iostream  -g -mt test2.cc

CC -G -h libtestsolaris.so test1.o test2.o -o libtestsolaris.so -library=iostream 

a-2720@N530 /data1/users/a-2720/samp :ls  -lrt test1.o test2.o libtestsolaris.so

-rw-rw-r--   1 a-2720   mcs        20944 May 18 06:16 test1.o

-rw-rw-r--   1 a-2720   mcs        20944 May 18 06:16 test2.o

-rwxrwxr-x   1 a-2720   mcs         7384 May 18 06:16 libtestsolaris.so
```

### LINUX

```
CC -m32 -c  -library=iostream  -g -mt test1.cc

CC -m32 -c  -library=iostream  -g -mt test2.cc

CC -m32 -G -h libtestlinux.so test1.o test2.o -o libtestlinux.so -library=iostream 

/data1/users/adarsh/samp :ls  -lrt test1.o test2.o libtestlinux.so

-rw-r--r-- 1 adarsh ifo 20220 May 18 06:44 test1.o

-rw-r--r-- 1 adarsh ifo 20220 May 18 06:44 test2.o

-rwxr-xr-x 1 adarsh ifo 41680 May 18 06:44 libtestlinux.so
```

Here we can see that the Linux shared library are in much bigger size than solaris once. Please note that the source file

for these libraries are same.
Our application uses thousand of files having these header files and hence a notable difference in size occurs.

We would like to know this size difference is a normal behavior of LINUX.

### System Details

```
/data1/users/adarsh/samp :cat /etc/*-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)

/data1/users/adarsh/samp :uname -a
Linux N280 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:48 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Compare the size of `libc` (or some other library your systems have in common) between the two. Might give you some clues.

Comment: Linux and Solaris are not acronyms.

Comment: `iostream` is a large complex library with a lot of implementation and compilation-option compromises, and different implementations may offer extensions affecting the object size.  Things like static lookup tables & inlining dominate your results.  For more meaningful comparison, use your entire app with typical deployment optimisation level after it's stripped (debug formats differ in quality and verbosity), and focus on resident set during real operation not on-disk object size or virtual size.  + What compiler are you using on each?  OS/CPU combinations (Intel and/or Sparc)?

Comment: Why is a 40KB library file a problem? Are you sure you compiled it without debug symbols and with optimization on?  In any case, 40KB is really tiny.

Answer (score 6):

`-g` option will [add debugging information](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options) to the executable, which will increase its size. Also turn on the [options that control various optimizations](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options).

Answer (score 0):

you could play with nm to see what code is in the library.

Answer (score 0):

1. do not build with debug symbols (-g option for gcc)
2. strip the symbols from the library

After doing steps 1 and 2, do the comparison.